# how to do string manipulation in c#

Tags: c#, string

how i can do this in c#

> Explosive;a dynamic person

if i do split then ; is removed from text

how i can make them

> Explosive;A dynamic person

Comment: at this rate there will be a SO question for every line of code in your app :) look at string.Join() to join it back together after you .Split() it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "Explosive;a dynamic person";
var separatorIndex = s.IndexOf(";");
if (separatorIndex != -1 && separatorIndex < s.Length + 1)
    s = s.Substring(0, separatorIndex + 1) + s.Substring(separatorIndex + 1, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(separatorIndex + 2);

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

gives "Explosive;A dynamic person"

I guess you would like something more general, but it is hard to figure out from the question how general you want it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to rejoin the results of the split using the same delimiter, `;` in this case.

```
string foo = "Explosive;a dynamic person";

string bar = string.Join(";",
    foo.Split(';')
       .Select(s =>
           s.Length == 0 ? s : s.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(1))
       .ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(bar);    // "Explosive;A dynamic person";
```

(And if you're using .NET 4 then you can omit the final `ToArray` call.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string str = "Explosive;a dynamic person";
int poz = str.IndexOf(";");

string part1 = str.Substring(0, poz + 1);
string part2 = str.Substring(poz + 1);

str = part1 + part2[0].ToString().ToUpper() + part2.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to:

1. Split the string
2. Capitalize the first character of each token
3. Join the results into a new string

This ought to do it:

```
string original = "Explosive;a dynamic person";
string[] split = original.Split(';');
string[] capitalized = split.Select(s => CapitalizeFirstLetter(s)).ToArray();
string joined = string.Join(";", capitalized);

string CapitalizeFirstLetter(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        return str;
    }

    char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
    char[0] = char.ToUpper(char[0]);

    return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works for your string:

```
var str = "String;a string!";
var index = str.IndexOf(";") + 1;
var newString = str.Substring(0,index);

if( str[index] != ' ' )
{
     newString += Char.ToUpper(str[index]);
     newString += str.Substring( index + 1 );
}

Console.WriteLine(newString);
```